# Is it possible to create a file with binary data without writing to file?

Tags: php, curl

I tried binding binary data to an array in a post request, but it doesn't work.

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 

$data = curl_exec($ch); 

curl_close($ch);
```

The API endpoints expect me to upload a file.

Is there a way to do the following with the binary data instead?

```
if (function_exists('curl_file_create')) { // php 5.5+
  $cFile = curl_file_create($file_name_with_full_path);
} else { // 
  $cFile = '@' . realpath($file_name_with_full_path);
}
$post = array('extra_info' => '123456','file_contents'=> $cFile);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

I don't want to upload the file to my directory before uploading it. I was trying to find a way to create a file in-memory and then put it inside of $post before doing a post to an API endpoint, but it seems that there's no way to do that, or is there?

Comment: What do you mean by binary data? Can you share some code?

Comment: `$cFile = 'hello I am data";`

Comment: I suppose that I should have noted that CurlFile and `@file` are _alternatives_ to just supplying the raw data for cases where reading a large file into a string beforehand would be counter-productive.